# Pulling all text (multple p tags) with BeautifulSoup and Selenium returns []

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the p tag comments within a review card, eventually looping through a search on vivino.com through this [link](https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwNyTEOgCAQBdHbbA2F5e-8gbE2uKyERBYCaOT20swrJlVYSlFhjaHkPixTHtg34pmVyvzhwutqlO5uyid8bJwf7UeRyqKdMrw0pgYdPwIzGwQ=) using BeautifulSoup and Selenium. I was able to open the first link but pulling the p text in the review boxes returns [].

```
url = "https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwNyTEOgCAQBdHbbA2F5e-8gbE2uKyERBYCaOT20swrJlVYSlFhjaHkPixTHtg34pmVyvzhwutqlO5uyid8bJwf7UeRyqKdMrw0pgYdPwIzGwQ="
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/myname/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

python_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('anchor__anchor--2QZvA')
python_button.click() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
print(soup.find_all('p'))

table = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"reviewCard__reviewContainer--1kMJM"})
print(table)
driver.quit()
```

Could anybody advise on the correct way to pull the comments? Since there are more than 1 comment per page would I need to loop?
I also tried this with 'html.parser' instead of 'lxml'. Which is the correct one to use?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You have used selenium,and you don't need to use beautifulsoup,it will be more slow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```
import atexit
from pprint import pprint

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import visibility_of_all_elements_located
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def start_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    atexit.register(driver.quit)
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver


def find_elements(driver, locator):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 2).until(visibility_of_all_elements_located(locator))


URL = "https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwNyTEOgCAQBdHbbA2F5e-8gbE2uKyERBYCaOT20swrJlVYSlFhjaHkPixTHtg34pmVyvzhwutqlO5uyid8bJwf7UeRyqKdMrw0pgYdPwIzGwQ="
RESULTS = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='vintageTitle'] > a"


def main():
    driver = start_driver()
    driver.get(URL)

    # note the results
    wines = []
    for element in find_elements(driver, RESULTS):
        link = element.get_attribute("href")
        name = element.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class*='vintageTitle__wine']").text
        wines.append((name, link))

    pprint(wines)

    # go extract details from each result's page
    for name, link in wines:
        print("getting comments for wine: ", name)
        driver.get(link)
        # you can do the rest ;)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```